# How can I resolve “The cursor was not declared” from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, websphere

I am connecting to SQL Server via Spring in WebSphere. I have a piece of pretty simple dynamic SQL (below) that is throwing "The cursor was not declared."

```
SELECT TOP 1
    short_desc shortDescription
FROM
    product.prs.PRODUCT_SKN (nolock)
WHERE
    prod_sales_div_code = 'XXX'
    AND product_nbr = ?
```

One of the settings for the data source that seems relevant is the "select mode" is "cursor". I'm not really sure what I need to do to resolve the error.

*edit* The calling code is:
`findShortDescriptionQuery.get().findObjectByNamedParam(of("productNumber", productId))`

Comment: Your last sentence about the 'data source' leads me to believe you are talking about client settings?  Do you get this error when you run this query from SSMS?  If not, you may want to change your question so it's more client centric.

Comment: I don't get the error in SSMS. I feel like it has to be a Spring or WebSphere setting

Comment: Or possibly a driver version or something..

Comment: Then you need to adjust your question.  iow: Post your calling code. ... otherwise nobody's going to be able to help you.  kwim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the "nolock" directive altogether, along with the "TOP 1", and the problem went away. This makes me suspect it is related to the JDBC driver.

This workaround is less than ideal, but will work just fine for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try saying `WITH (nolock)` rather than just `(nolock)`. The latter syntax is no longer supported on recent versions of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Check which database on the server you're using. If you have different databases at the same server, your sql client will by default usually pick "master" or some such to run the query against if you don't specify. Selecting the one that contains the table you're querying or using `USE <dbname> GO` before the query will handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much relevance this answer may have, after 10 years, but working on some old code I stumbled upon this same "error", and I solved it by removing the field list from the query, leaving the inefficient `SELECT *`. This solved the problem for me.

BTW, the old code uses *Microsoft SQL Server ODBC* drivers to access the **SQL Server**, and it seems that the problem is exactly that, 'cause the same query run on SSMS works without issues'.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently same issue..
Solved the problem by rewriting all queries with CTE.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT..
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Currently looking for same issue with stored procedures called from Internet Information Services.